# RDLC Body size is not decreasing

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc

I am using RDLC Report to build an invoice (Bill)

I used tablix in the body part of the RDLC report, I had setup the report sise to A4 and my tabix has only 1 or 2 rows and it still consuming  the blank space in the body part.

I also set the `ConsumeContainerWriteSpace` to true but still no luck.

Edit:
[Invoice image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm1j8.jpg)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Can you share image showing what you want and what you are getting?

Comment: I had updatee the queation, have a look to the image